# Is $R=K[\![x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3]\!]$ a Gorenstein ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay, gorenstein

Let $K$ be a field and $R=K[\![x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3]\!]$ the ring of formal power series. Is  $R$ a Gorenstein ring?

$R$ is Cohen-Macaulay of dimension 2.

So, I have to check if $Ext^2_{K}(K,R)=K.$

Comment: You can obtain double brackets by using a negative spacing `\!`: $k[\![x]\!]$ is obtained by `k[\![ X]\!]`.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff thanks for the tip. It will help me too.